# Adding a new row in data using the existing rows and based on a column using SQL

Tags: sql, r, group-by, common-table-expression

[image]

I have the data in the attached format in R. I am making use of sqldf to solve the following challenge :

I need to add the yellow cells to my existing data(the light orange cells). The Total amount should be added as a row in the existing data considering Type 1,2,3,4 based on the color. All in column Color refers to both categories (B & W).All in column Product refers to Product Type 1, 2, 3 & 4. I have used the following code

```
select country, state, district, color, product, amount from Table
union all
select distinct country, state, district, color, "All", sum(amount) from Table
group by country, state, district, color
```

I end up getting either 0 in the amount or end up getting multiple Alls with 0 corresponding to the rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try applying a partial aggregation with window functions + distinct keyword in the second select statement:

```
select country, state, district, color, product, amount from Table
union all
select distinct country, state, district, color, "All",
                sum(amount) over(partition by country, state, district, color)
from Table
```

This should work on all the most common DBMS', which sqldf is currently interfacing with.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, would try and run the same on my R Studio. But before running your suggested code, wanted to understand if there is a need to apply group by ? I wrote - **group by country, state, district, color** and excluded **product** from the group by since I created "All" for it. Since the number of rows is humongous , thought of getting rid of my curiosity before running the code.

Comment: No need to apply `GROUP BY` with window functions: it is used when you're aggregating explicitly (as you were doing in your query with the `SUM` aggregate function). Here we're doing an implicit aggregation with the `DISTINCT` keyword and using the `SUM` window function. I'd suggest you to look at the intermediate outputs of the second query first without the distinct, then with the distinct. Eventually try the full query and compare the final output.

Comment: Thanks, worked quite well, infact,  applied three union alls using this logic to get to the desired output